# How to filter JSON object in SnowSQL query

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a json object and I would like to run a select that excludes some keys.

For instance:

If I have the object:

```
"product-list": {
    "product": {
        "commit-timestamp": "2023-01-01T09:19:45.123000Z",
        "operation": "update",
        "partition-key-type": "primary-key",
        "partition-key-value": "12345",
        "record-type": "data",
    }
}
```

Then I would like to select:

```
"product": {
    "operation": "update",
    "partition-key-type": "primary-key",
    "partition-key-value": "12345",
    "record-type": "data",
}
```

In the example above, I am excluding the *commit-timestamp*.  Note that I will be doing this for several different json objects, so it is not feasible to simply reconstruct the object without the one key

Here is my query so far.

```
select json[product-list]
from some_table
```

I have attempted to use json selectors, but that doesn't work with SnowSQL since it just supports basic dot and bracket notation.  Is this even possible in Snowflake?

Comment: Look into https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_delete

Comment: as per Kathmandude's comment you ether need to delete all object nodes you do not want, or actively rebuild the object. They both have down failure modes with respect to change, that needs to be evaluated for you use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript UDFs to manipulate objects. You cannot add libraries to the Javascript environment, but baseline Javascript includes good methods to select, add, delete, and change JSON keys and values.

```
create or replace function transform_json("obj" variant)
returns variant
language javascript strict immutable
as
$$

    obj = obj["product-list"];
    delete obj.product["commit-timestamp"];
    return obj;

$$;


with X as
(
select parse_json($$
{
    "product-list": {
        "product": {
            "commit-timestamp": "2023-01-01T09:19:45.123000Z",
            "operation": "update",
            "partition-key-type": "primary-key",
            "partition-key-value": "12345",
            "record-type": "data"
        }
    }
}
$$) as json
)
select json, transform_json(json) from X
;
```

Transformed output:

```
{
  "product": {
    "operation": "update",
    "partition-key-type": "primary-key",
    "partition-key-value": "12345",
    "record-type": "data"
  }
}
```